# How to replace output of SELECT statemnt in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT id, descr Category, parent_id `Department`, updated `Updated`
     , updatedby `By`
FROM category
```

which returns numbers at the column parent_id. It can only return one of three number (167, 154, 164) at parent_id column. I want to replace those numbers with:

```
164 - Advertisemnt
167 - Modeling
154 - Finance
```

How can that be achieved? 
so , the table should look like:

```
id category Department Updated By

1  Network  Modeling   now()   Me
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use as CASE statement like this:

```
SELECT id
      ,descr AS `Category`
      ,CASE parent_id 
         WHEN 164 THEN 'Advertisemnt'
         WHEN 167 THEN 'Modeling'
         WHEN 154 THEN 'Finance'
         ELSE          'Unknown partent_id'
       END AS `Department`
     ,updated AS `Updated`
     ,updatedby AS `By`
FROM  category
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the department names aren't available in a table?

If you want to hard code the department names you can do like this:

```
SELECT id, descr Category, 
       case parent_id when 154 then 'Finance' 
                      when 164 then 'Advertisement'
                      when 167 then 'Modeling' 
       end case "Department", 
       updated "Updated", updatedby "By" 
  FROM category
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I forgot about CASE, I think is better suited, see other answers.

Use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT id, descr as Category, 
if(parent_id='164', 'Advertisemnt', 
    if(parent_id='167','Modeling',
        if(parent_id='154, 'Finance', '')
    )
 ) as Department, updated as Updated, updatedby as By FROM category;
```

Those strings can't be read from another table ? Thay are hardcoded in the scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a CASE statement like [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) should do the trick.

Update: If you have a flexible list of items, it might be useful to put them in a separate table and refer them with foreign keys.